# javascript function doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, html, this

The following html-webpage contains a button. If you click the button contained in the page, the color of the button is supposed to turn red (according to the js-code). However, it does not work and I do not understand why it does not work.
In fact, nobody around me understands why it doesn't work. If somebody knows what's going on, please help me!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>

            <h1>Please click the button below, it will turn red.</h1>

            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)">Set background color</button>

            <script>
                function myFunction(element) {
                element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

UPDATE: the above code works, sorry for this. I had simplified my original code before posting it here. My goal was to reduce the code to the essential part.
Below you find the original code. If I press the button twice, it is supposed to turn green. However, it stays red. And I don't understand why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>

        <h1>Please click the button below, it will turn red.</h1>

        <button type="button" onclick="setColor(this)">Set background   color</button>

        <script>
            lastField = null;
            function setColor(element) {
            if (element === lastField) {
                element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }

            element.style.backgroundColor = "red";

            lastField = element; 
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/gataqo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: working like charm

Comment: Check the browser for any JavaScript errors.

Comment: Even your code snippet works.

Comment: Your `if` statement sets the background to green. The next line of code sets it back to red, regardless of whether the `if` is true or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time you click it, `lastField` is null, so the background is set to red and `lastField` is set to the element.

The second time you click it, `lastField` is the element, so the background is set to green … then the background is immediately set to red and `lastField` is set to the element.

The third and subsequence times are identical to the second time.

You need an `else` in there.